# Integration testing in Laravel

Tags: php, integration-testing, laravel-10

I am currently learning how to perform tests in Laravel. I created an integration test of the Product controller in the ProductController test and tested the store function.

```
class ProductControllerTest extends TestCase
{
    /**
     * A basic feature test example.
     */
    use RefreshDatabase;

    public function test_store_product(): void
    {
        $product = Product::factory()->make()->toArray();
        $user = User::factory()->create();

        $response = $this
            ->actingAs($user)
            ->post(route('product.store'), $product)
            ->assertSessionHasNoErrors()
            ->assertForbidden();

        // Assert that the response has a successful status code
        $response->assertStatus(302);

        $this->assertDatabaseHas('products', $product);
    }
}
```

**ProductFactory**

```
    public function definition(): array
    {
        return [
            'name' => 'Clothing',
            'promotional_price' => '900',
            'original_price' => '1000',
            'saving' => '10',
            'size' => 'small',
            'image_filename' => 'image.jpg',
        ];
    }
```

**ProductController**

```
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        // Validate the request
        $request->validate([
            'image' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif|max:2048',
        ]);

        //Calculate the promotional price
        $promotionalPrice = $request->price * (1- ($request->saving/100));
        //Change the image name and move it to the public folder under images
        $imageName = time().'.'.$request->image->extension();
        $request->image->move(public_path('images'), $imageName);


        Product::create([
            'name' => $request->name,
            'original_price' => $request->price,
            'promotional_price' => $promotionalPrice,
            'saving' => $request->saving,
            'size' => $request->size,
            'image_filename' => $imageName,
        ]);

        return redirect()->route('dashboard')->with('success', 'Product created successfully!');
    }
```

When I run the php artisan test, I get the error that the image field is required, even though I have it on my factory. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `create()` method in your factory instead of `make()`. The create() method not only creates an instance of the model but also persists it to the database.

```
public function test_store_product(): void
{
    $product = Product::factory()->create()->toArray();
    $user = User::factory()->create();

    $response = $this
        ->actingAs($user)
        ->post(route('product.store'), $product)
        ->assertSessionHasNoErrors()
        ->assertForbidden();

    // Assert that the response has a successful status code
    $response->assertStatus(302);

    $this->assertDatabaseHas('products', $product);
}
```